# Tag, Send messages and post messages in LinkedIn - programatically

Tags: linkedin-api, tagging, linkedin-jsapi, linkedin-gem, cross-posting

Is it possible to send messages or tag (people) to strangers / non connections in LinkedIn programatically? I would also like to know if it is possible to post in groups with out being a member in the group in LinkedIn.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot tag people in Shares via the API right now.  That only happens when posting through linkedin.com

You have to be a group member to post to a group, regardless of whether it's public or private.